# How do I set Cache-Control/Expires Headers

Tags: html, tomcat

I want to use expires headers or Cache-Control, but I don't know how to do that. I searched a little bit on Google and I found different tags but I don't know if it's ok to use them or  whether it's deprecated.

Example:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="max-age=86400, must-revalidate">
```

I use Tomcat server and also found different methods to do that directly on server through `web.xml` file (which isn't working trough server settings).

If anyone can help me with a solution I will really appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Explain to me, why is this tagged `Java`? Where do you want to set `Cache-Control` (on server, on java code, on HTML, etc.)?

Comment: The better solution is to set this on server or HTML. Sorry for java tag

Answer (score 0):

In the Servlet.service method

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=86400, must-revalidate");
```

Or put that in a filter.